# What does the delay mean in rxjs?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

### 1st example

- there's a input#input in the dom and a div#field to present what typed in the inputElem
- then subscribe

  1. when I typed {..v.a..b.l.e}, the div#field s display `value` after 5s as expect
  2. then I stop for a while then type {.of..this.} in the input
  3. IMO the delay already execute so the `valueofthis` should be present immediately, but actually not. what' s the problem?

### in the 2nd example

what's the different between these two example?

```
const Observable = Rx.Observable

const inputElem = document.getElementById('input')
const fieldElem = document.getElementById('field')
const inputTexts = Observable.fromEvent(inputElem, 'input')
                              .map(e => e.target.value)
                              .delay(5000)



inputTexts.subscribe(x=> fieldElem.textContent=x , 
                           ()=> {},
                           ()=> {console.log('completed')})


//2.
   var values = Observable.of(1,2,4,8)
                          .map(v => 2*v)
                          .delay(4000)

   values.subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/delay.html

Comment: Because every value that goes through your `observable` passes through the operators on that said `observable` ?

Answer (score 1):

The [delay](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html) operator, like all Rx operators, works by returning a *new* Observable to which the operators function is applied. It doesn't change the source Observable itself.

So in the second example, the line where you apply `delay` to `values` is actually not having any effect.

```
   var values = Observable.of(1,2,4,8)
                          .map(v => 2*v)
   values.delay(4000) // Oops! we've lost the Observable returned from `delay`
   values.subscribe(x => console.log(x)) // prints without delay
```

You need to use the Observable returned from `delay` in order for it to behave like you expect. This is normally done with chaining, like:

```
   var values = Observable.of(1,2,4,8)
                          .map(v => 2*v)
                          .delay(4000)  // values gets return value of delay
   values.subscribe(x => console.log(x)) // prints to console after 4s
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I edited the second example as u point out. Now, the question is what's the different between 1at and 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for delay](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-delay) says that:

> ...this operator time shifts the source Observable by that amount of
>   time expressed in milliseconds. *The relative time intervals between
>   the values are preserved*.

In your first example, there are two 'input' events (values) emitted by the source Observable: one emitted when you first change the value (at time t=0), and then one emitted some seconds later (at t=n) when you next change it. The `delay` operator causes them both to be delayed by the same amount of time (5 seconds), and so you see them reach your subscriber at t=(0+5)=5 and t=(n+5). The second event is delayed the same amount as the first, so they will still be `n` seconds apart.

In the second example, `Observable.of` emits each of its values at almost exactly the same time (t=0). After going through `delay`, the resulting values reach your subscriber, still at almost the same time, at t=4.